# Force divs to have the same height with images inside

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to find a way that forces all divs to be the same height as the highest div in the element. I've found a good source in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKPnrasaxDJbGU7pyrWk?p=preview)

When I open the page all the divs have the same height, but the problem is when I resize the browser the images get resized but the divs stay the same height which causes some distortion.

```
.directive('equalizeHeight', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: function($scope){
        console.log('equalizeHeightFor - controller');
        var elements = [];
        this.addElement = function(element){
          console.log('adding element:', element);
          elements.push(element);
          console.log(elements);
        }

        // resize elements once the last element is found
        this.resize = function(){
          $timeout(function(){
            console.log('finding the tallest ...');
            // find the tallest
            var tallest = 0, height;
            angular.forEach(elements, function(el){
              height = el[0].offsetHeight;
              console.log('height:', height);
              if(height > tallest)
                tallest = height;
              // console.log(el);
            });
            console.log('tallest:', tallest);
            console.log('resizing ...');
            // resize
            angular.forEach(elements, function(el){
              el[0].style.height = tallest + 'px';
            });
            console.log('-- finished --');
          }, 0);
        };
      }
    };
  }])

  .directive('equalizeHeightAdd', [function($timeout){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^^equalizeHeight',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl_for){
        console.log('equalizeHeightAdd - link');
        // add element to list of elements
        ctrl_for.addElement(element);
        if(scope.$last)
          ctrl_for.resize();
      }
    };
  }])
  ;
```

Comment: Try to bind your `resize` function to the $window resize event.

Comment: You're gonna be much better off using flexbox if you can (depending on target browsers).

Comment: @Triptych that does look pretty good! Thanks for the suggestion. Going to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. Use flexbox. Here's [an article describing your use case](http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback). I googled "flexbox equal height".